# Store a dynamic value for a custom Woocommerce plugin

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

[image: Example]

I read different articles, but they describe more other things. I do not want to make the wrong code with too much space. In the module there will be one single value that can be changed in the admin panel and other extraneous functions. How correctly to create a database for value of this window in a plugin?
I found the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins), but I do not have enough experience to cut the excess, if it is.

My code `/plugins/custom-counter/custom-counter.php`

```
/*
Plugin Name: Custom Counter
Plugin URI: https://example.com
Description: This plugin adds counter.
Author: Kuznetsova Alexandra
Author URI: https://example.com
*/

// Hook for adding admin menus
add_action('admin_menu', 'custom_counter_menu');

// action function for above hook
function custom_counter_menu() {
    // Add a submenu to Woocommerce menu:
    add_submenu_page('woocommerce', 'Custom Counter', 'Custom Counter', 'administrator', 'custom-counter', 'custom_counter_page');
}

// custom_counter_page() displays the page content
function custom_counter_page() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Custom Counter</h2>

        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php settings_fields( 'baw-settings-group' ); ?>
            <table class="form-table">
                <tr valign="top">
                    <th scope="row">Total Counter</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="custom-counter" value="..." /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <p class="submit">
                <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Save Changes') ?>" />
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated** - As this is a unique value that will be updated multiple times, you can use the `wp_options` table with the following WordPress dedicated functions:

- [`get_option($option);`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/) where `$option` is the name of option to retrieve
- [`update_option($option, $new_value);`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option) where `$option` is the name of option and `$new_value` the new value to be updated.

The fact that options are cached is not a problem if you use some tricks as you will see below, to avoid this data to be cached.

So try the following code:

```
// Add a custom admin submenu to Woocommerce
add_action('admin_menu', 'custom_counter_menu');
function custom_counter_menu() {
    add_submenu_page('woocommerce', 'Custom Counter', 'Custom Counter', 'administrator', 'custom-counter', 'custom_counter_page');
}

// Content for the custom Woocommerce admin submenu
function custom_counter_page() {
    $option_name = 'wc-custom-counter' ;
    if( isset($_POST[$option_name]) ){
        $new_value = sanitize_text_field( $_POST[$option_name] );
        if ( get_option( $option_name ) !== false ) {
            update_option($option_name, $new_value );
        } else {
            add_option( $option_name, $new_value, null, 'no' );
        }
    }
    $default = ''; // Set the default value
    $value = get_option( $option_name ) ? get_option( $option_name ) : $default;
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2><?php _e('Custom Counter'); ?></h2>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <?php settings_fields( 'baw-settings-group' ); ?>
            <table class="form-table">
                <tr valign="top">
                    <th scope="row"><?php _e('Total Counter'); ?></th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="<?php echo $option_name; ?>" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <p class="submit">
                <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Save Changes') ?>" />
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php 
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). tested and work.

> If the option already exist, to avoid caching issue, you should need to delete it using:
>
> ```
> delete_option('wc-custom-counter');
> ```
>
> And adding it in your function.php file. Then browse any page of your web site and remove it.

Comment: Thank you for the full answer and explanation!

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to store one thing, like a setting, then you can use [wp_options](https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API). You can then use WordPress functions to interact with the database instead of writing your own SQL.

Comment: If it is a constantly changing number, then it is also not necessary to create a database?

Comment: Are you just updating the same number or are you creating a new number for every entry?

Comment: This is a counter that will always increase. From the admin panel I can delete the value. Then it will increase again with the help of a third-party function.

Comment: Okay... So I think it will only be one entry that needs CRUD functionality. The 4 functions for CRUD functionality are in that link under Examples.

Comment: Thank you! I will check this option and accept the answer if it works for this task.

Comment: Cool! If it doesn’t work let me know and we’ll try something else.

Comment: Maybe it does not fit. Honestly there is not enough experience to check this, but found the information that the value falls into the cache, which is probably not very good in this case. "Upon getting an option in code, this option value will be cached. If you modify any options outside of the Options API, then try to update an option that's already cached, this will fail updating and return false. You can use the following method to clear the options cache before trying to get or update the options on the same request". [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option)

Comment: If wp_options doesn't work for you then you can try using [wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) to create your own table and update accordingly.